# faster method of counting values if the value meets the condition python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

does anyone know a faster method of counting values from the list in  Python if the condition is met.

```
today = datetime.date.today()
d = datetime.date.today() + timedelta(days=1)
d1 = datetime.date.today() + timedelta(days=2)
d2 = datetime.date.today() + timedelta(days=3)
d3 = datetime.date.today() + timedelta(days=5)
USERWARD = {"USER":[[["value1"], ["value2"],  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [ "LEARNED", d, d2, today, d3, d, d1, d2]],
                    [["value2"], ["value3"],  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [ d, d2, today, d3, d, d1, d2 ,"LEARNED"]],
                    [["value4"], ["value5"],  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [ d, d1, d2 ,"LEARNED", d, d2, today, d3]]]}
users = "USER"
uservalue = USERWARD[users]
count_english = 0
for i in range(len(uservalue)):
    date=(uservalue[i][4][0])
    try:
        if date <= today:
                count_english +=1                 
    except TypeError:
            continue
```

Answer (score 0):

If by faster you mean in less code, you could use a list comprehension:
`count = len([1 for u in uservalue if u[4][0] <= today])`

If by faster you really mean runs in less time, you could try using the `multiprocessing` module to determine the condition in parallel and then count the number of `True` cases.